# What's the significance of this string format in URLs?

Tags: url, encoding, content-management-system, schema

I have been inspecting a variety of websites recently and keep encountering URLs containing strings like this, sometimes capitalised, sometimes not:

```
  c8e700e6-4166-11e7-82b6-896b95f30f58
```

Does anyone know the significance or origin of this? Is it an encoding schema, something to do with the webapp framework, or something else?

Thanks

Comment: Looks like a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier). So it's just an id for something. These things are just long numbers, usually printed in hexadecimal. Which explains that it is somethime capitalised and sometime not.

Comment: Ah of course thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In technical terms, it's called a [UUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) or a universally unique identifier (aka GUID).  The purpose is almost always to ensure that the page loaded by the browser is a unique URL and therefore not cached, but it can also be used to uniquely identify a session with the server.

It's not usually considered to be best practice to do it this way.

Comment: Or the id of a ressource if the url is REST-like

Comment: @litelite Maybe, but usually not.  GUIDs are generated and have low possibility to clash with others, but usually database ids are simply sequential numbers.

Comment: to my knowledge, they are frequently used in databases or at least in NoSQL databases because they can easilly be generated on different node in sharded databases. And anyway the probability of clashing is so low that it might as well not exist. (It's like 1/2 chances if you generate a few billion per second for a century)

Comment: @litelite Hmm, I didn't consider NoSQL type databases.  You may have a point.

Answer (score 0):

This is a GUID, use for better future unity.
Remove the possibilities of conflict on database of two companies.
PS:Sorry for my English.

Comment: Or in databases that are splitted across several servers.